# gitlab and jira integration (smart commits)

Tags: gitlab, jira, integration

I have integration between gitlab and Jira. i can close my Issue in Jira and 
commits linked to issue same. But I want use smart commits for change my jira issue status through git commit.
I tried as:

```
ADMIN-53 #start
ADMIN-53 #start-progress
```

for move my task to "In progress" status, but it doesn't work.
During set up integration between Jira and Gitlab I specified all status ID from jira workflow. For better result my git branch has the same name which jira task.

Comment: any luck with this? not working for me either.